# MVC - System.Web.HttpException: Maximum request length exceeded

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have the following code in my web.config...

```
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
    </modules>

    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>

    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
  </system.webServer>
```

I have a page where I allow a user to upload up to five images. In testing this, I am attempting to upload five images, totalling ~16MB and I'm getting the maximum request length exceeded error. Is there something else I need to set?

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853767/maximum-request-length-exceeded, seems duplicate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1073741824" />
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
       <!-- Your other settings -->
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

In addition to what you have set. You probably also want to look at the executiontimeout (also a property of [`httpRuntime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/e1f13641%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).

Comment: Tho 1073741824 is 1GB, so you may want to tweek it down on both settings? :-)